# Can `helm-ag` commands ignore git submodules?

Tags: helm, helm-ag

When I am running `helm-ag` commands in a large project with multiple git submodules, the shared libaries are repeatedly searched. I do not want those be searched.

So how can I change the `helm-ag` commands' behavior to achieve that?

The `helm-ag` library I mentioned above is here:
https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-ag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding a `.agignore` (or [`.ignore`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/wiki/Advanced-Usage) if you use ag 2.0.0) to the root of your project with a list of folders that you want to ignore.  You have to set `helm-ag-use-grep-ignore-list` to non-nil value to use this file.

There is other way to do that by only changing your emacs configuration.  You set `helm-ag-use-grep-ignore-list` to non-nil value and add the directories that you want to ignore to [`grep-find-ignored-directories`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/grep.el#L219-L226).  You can find an example of use of `grep-find-ignored-directories` in [Endless Parentheses](http://endlessparentheses.com/exclude-directories-from-grep.html).

Comment: This does not work with helm-do-ag.